# Recovering "raw" history from current bash session

Tags: bash, shell, recover, input-history

I managed to truncate my bash history file to 500 entries by running a shell that didn't have any of my configuration (it was vanilla).

I realized this about 300 commands too late, but luckily I had a session open from before the truncate.  `history` in that session gives me my "deleted" history, but it's in this format:

```
  449  05/07/21 02:04:03 ncdu
```

and the first 300 entries are the truncated file and not the original 300.

I figure the actual 300 entries must be stored somewhere.  How do I obtain them?  I only have the one session with the old history.

Additionally, I'd like to obtain the previous history in the following format, if possible:

```
#1635749826
ll
```

Comment: Is the number in comments a unix timestamp?

Comment: if so, it wouldn't be too hard to run a python script to yoink each timestamp from the old file and paste the unix timestamp followed by the command

Comment: Yes, it is a timestamp and it'd be pretty easy.  But still, if we are to recover the first 300 entries we might as well get a proper, usable file. 

It's not as much about having those entries as figuring out how to obtain them.

Comment: dump the history output to a file (for safe keeping) and perhaps try `history -a` (from `help history` => `-a : append history lines from this session to the history file`); perhaps test on another session first?

Comment: @markp-fuso that worked!  It seems to have overwritten my new bash history (which I did back up)

It did not, however, bring the first 500 back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`history -a` will overwrite your bash history file with the history returned by the `history` command for the current session.

You need to copy your current bash history, and can then append it to the original file.

It does not, however, bring back the first 500 entries.

Thanks to @markp-fuso for this solution.